# Using pine editor v5, how can I draw a vertical line on the last candle of the day on every friday

Tags: pine-script, line, indicator, pine-editor

How can I change the following code to draw a vertical line at the end of every Friday instead of drawing a triangle? Is there a more simple code strategy than what I'm using?

```
//@version=5    
indicator("Friday Vertical Line", overlay=true)

var line fridayLine = na

// Check if it's Friday    
isFriday = dayofweek == dayofweek.friday

// Check if it's the last candle of the day    
isLastCandleOfDay = hour == 16 and minute == 0

// Draw a triangle only on the last candle of the day on Fridays    
plotshape(series=isLastCandleOfDay and isFriday, color=color.orange, style=shape.triangleup, location=location.belowbar, size=size.small)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you already use `isFriday` and `isLastCandleOfDay` in your `plotshape()` condition.

Use the same expression and call `line.new()`.

```
if (isLastCandleOfDay and isFriday)
    line.new(bar_index, close, bar_index, close + syminfo.mintick, color=color.orange, extend=extend.both)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but unfortunately that code draws a bunch of horizontal lines across the screen.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question. My original answer was drawing horizontal lines. I just edited my answer and showed you a way to draw vertical lines with `line.new()`.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I was able to get the desired result by using the bgcolor command.

Answer (score 0):

‍♀️ the ***bgcolor*** command did exactly what I needed it to do.